# How do i implement a search bar which fetches information using an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I am trying to build an application using "Rick and Morty" REST API. I have created the "card.js" component which fetches data from the API such as characters, name, id, species, and I am mapping on the cards in my "cardList.js" component.

What I am trying to do:

**1)** I am trying to implement a search bar over the top of the application, which will display a specific card based on what I have searched, let's say i have searched "Rick", so it will display all the cards which has "Rick" in its name.
**2)** Further, we can also search for anything related to the parameters that i have specified in the card such as gender, type etc.

What I tried already:

**1)** I created a component called "Search2.js"
**2)** In this component, I have a "form" which contains the input type, and a button to search the input which the user has entered.
**3)** In the "cardList.js" component I passed the "Search2.js" component over the "card.js" component so that it stays at the top(search bar and the button)
**4)** I am mapping over "Search2.js" in my "CardList.js" component to pass the characters as props in my "Search2.js" component, and luckily i am getting all the characters in my console when i am doing console.log({this.props.name}).

The problem:
**1)** I am getting confused how do i compare individual names(from this.props.name) with the input i have provided in my form in the "Search2.js" component
**2)** I tried, but all i am getting is my form which is mapped over 493 times(it is the number of characters in the API)

My Card.js component:

```
import React from "react";

class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ID: {this.props.id}</h1>
        <img src={this.props.imgURL} alt="Image failed to load" />
        <h1>NAME: {this.props.name}</h1>
        <h2>STATUS: {this.props.status}</h2>
        <h3>SPECIES: {this.props.species}</h3>
        <h3>GENDER: {this.props.props}</h3>
        <h4>TYPE: {this.props.type}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

My CardList.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "./Card";
import Search from "./Search";
import Search2 from "./Search2";

class CardList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    // url: `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${[...Array(494).keys()]}`,
    character: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    //const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    const ids = Array(493)
      .fill(null)
      .map((_, idx) => idx + 1)
      .join(","); // '1,2,3...,300'
    const url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/[${ids}]`;
    const res = await axios.get(url);

    this.setState({
      character: res.data
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.character.map(character => (
          <Search2 name={character.name} />
        ))}
        {this.state.character.map(character => (
          <Card
            key={character.id}
            imgURL={character.image}
            id={character.id}
            name={character.name}
            status={character.status}
            species={character.species}
            gender={character.gender}
            type={character.type ? character.type : "Unknown"}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardList;
```

My Search2.js component :

```
import React from "react";

class Search2 extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const searchValue = event.target.value;

    if (searchValue === "{this.props.name}") {
      console.log("matched");
    } else {
      console.log("doesnt match");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter character" name="fullName" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <button>Search2</button>
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Search2;
```

Help me out, please!!

Comment: what is the root component here?

Comment: Root component is App.js where i am rendering all the components, i did not include all of that detail because it was not important and necessary!

Comment: You should not make `componentDidMount` async. Instead call an async function in componentDidMount, but do not wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

My idea to help you solve this problem goes like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>

        {
let filter=this.state.character.filter(function(e)
{
//here you can filter out anything you want, for example:
return e.name.includes("Rick") // <- this will check the data you already got from axios //to filter out for every name that contains "Rick', you can then replace "Rick" with your input's value, using State or anything you like
}

filter.map(character => (
          <Card
            key={character.id}
            imgURL={character.image}
            id={character.id}
            name={character.name}
            status={character.status}
            species={character.species}
            gender={character.gender}
            type={character.type ? character.type : "Unknown"}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this way you will firstly filter out data, then you map this as you did before, but this time it will only show records that get through your filter process

Here you can check the idea behind it [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xcd8y2he/4/)

Comment: I don't think I get it well, would you like to fork my repository and alter my code if I provide you with the Github repo link?

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul I propose you would have more success, if you provide a fully functioning JSFiddle with the issue, then one can alter the JSFiddle

Comment: why are we passing (e) in the function? what does that signify?

Comment: that `e` mean the element while filtering (the same that when you use `.map`)

Also with a simple check in the documentation  https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/  of that api they have an endpoint to retrieve ALL the characters, and you don't need to append all the ids in the url 

https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#get-all-characters

And if you need to make an async request by filtering they also provide some ways https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#filter-characters  instead of retrieving all the info and filter over it

Comment: No, we cannot get all the characters, in the documentation, we can only get up to 20 characters at a time, to get all 493 characters, we need to append all the id's